# How import text (csv) data into Libre Office Calc without auto-conversion to numbers

Tags: libreoffice-calc

when importing csv data, i have a column where most of the text strings are all numerals, but many also have letters.  Calc will invariably strip leading zeros from a string that is all numerals, and will also interpret a string with an 'E' as scientific notation.

There is a 'detect special numbers' checkbox in the import dialog, and an 'auto input' checkbox under the tools menu.  Neither of these affect the behavior.

data file:

99762
0099762
9834G7
9834E7

expected is same text.

actual is:

99762
99762
9834G7
98340000000

Libre Office version 6.0.7.3, buildid 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.8

Answer (score 2):

in the import dialog, i can select a column and specify it should be imported as text.  that works fine.

:-)

Comment: This is an unexpected thing to have to but god this is helpful. One thing I noticed though is that a fixed width import can have at minimum two columns